# Accessing a computed property outside of a method

Tags: swift

I have a generic function inside a class in which a computed property is declared:

```
 class CalculatorBrain {
var internalProgram = [AnyObject]()
var accumulator: Double = 0.0
var variableValues: Dictionary<String,Double> = [:]   

 func setOperand<T> (operand: T) {
    if operand is Double {
        accumulator = operand as! Double
        internalProgram.append(operand as AnyObject)
    }
    else if variableName == operand as? String {
        var dictionaryValue: Double? {
            get {
                return variableValues[variableName!]
            }
            set {
                accumulator = newValue!
                internalProgram.append(newValue! as AnyObject)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want to set dictionaryValue to the value shown in the display from the view controller:

```
private var brain = CalculatorBrain()

 @IBAction func setVariableValue(_ sender: UIButton) {

    brain.dictionaryValue = displayValue

}
```

Obviously I can't, because dictionaryValue is locally defined and "Value of type CalculatorBrain has no memeber dictionaryValue" Now the question is, how can I make a computed property global, and make changes to it from inside a class method? Or, how can I access a computed property defined inside a class method from outside the function?

Comment: plz share more code to get it understand

Comment: The question is: I have a computed property in a function inside a class, and I can  neither access it from outside the function nor make it global in the class. What should I do?

Comment: variables declared within function are local to function and we can not access it outside of function. You can easily declare computed properties at class level. Can I know what is `variableName` in else if condition in function?

Comment: I want the changes made to the variable to happen inside the function (that's why the setter is written there) but I also want to access it outside the function.
setOperand takes two kinds of operands, and variableName is the name of the string operands it takes which is a variable whose value is given through the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is dictionaryValue is not a computed property of your class, it is just a variable declared in the setOperand function, so it is not accessible from outside the function.

You should declare it as a stored property of your class and change it when setOperand is called.

Comment: Yes, that's totally right. But at first I'd defined it as dictionaryValue:Double? in the class, and when I changed it from the controller, the setter in the setOperand didn't get called. As if there were two dictionaryValues independent from each other, one stored in the class and the other computed in the method.

Comment: Obviously you can't have the getter and setter inside the function, since dictionaryValues needs to be a property of your class, so you can only implement a custom getter/setter for it in your class definition. But if its a stored property, you don't need the getter anyways and you can just directly change the value of dictionaryValues in setOperand instead of using a setter inside setOperand.

Comment: So, if I both want the changes to the property to be applied inside setOperand and access the property outside it, there's no way for me to declare the setter in the method?